# Under what circumstances does the iterator of ranges::split_view not satisfy copyable?

Tags: c++, c++20, range-v3, std-ranges

C++20 introduces a [`ranges::split_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/split_view), which accepts a `view` and a delimiter, and splits the `view` into subranges according to the delimiter.

The delimiter is also a `view`, and when it is a single element, it will be wrapped in a `ranges::single_view`.

Each returned subrange is also a `view`, its type is `split_view::outer-iterator::value_type`, which is defined in [[range.adaptors#range.split.outer.value]](http://eel.is/c++draft/range.adaptors#range.split.outer.value):

```
template<bool Const>
struct split_view<V, Pattern>::outer-iterator<Const>::value_type
  : view_interface<value_type> {
private:
  outer-iterator i_ = outer-iterator();               // exposition only
public:
  value_type() = default;
  constexpr explicit value_type(outer-iterator i) : i_(std​::​move(i)) {}

  constexpr inner-iterator<Const> begin() const requires copyable<outer-iterator>
  constexpr inner-iterator<Const> begin() requires (!copyable<outer-iterator>);
  constexpr default_sentinel_t end() const;
};
```

The return type of `begin()` and `end()` of this inner `view` are `inner-iterator` and `default_sentinel_t`, but it is not important to the problem. The problem lies in the two constrained `begin()` functions [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/range.adaptors#range.split.outer.value-3):

```
constexpr inner-iterator<Const> begin() const requires copyable<outer-iterator>
{ return inner-iterator<Const>{i_­}; }

constexpr inner-iterator<Const> begin() requires (!copyable<outer-iterator>);
{ return inner-iterator<Const>{std::move(i_)­}; }
```

The `begin()` function chooses whether to move the underlying `i_` according to whether its type  `outer-iterator` is `copyable`, which looks reasonable.

However, this constraint seems useless, the reason is that `outer-iterator` seems to always satisfy `copyable`. In [[range.adaptors#range.split.outer]](http://eel.is/c++draft/range.adaptors#range.split.outer), the `outer-iterator`, which is the iterator type of the `split_view`, is defined as:

```
template<bool Const>
struct split_view<V, Pattern>::outer-iterator {
private:
  using Parent = maybe-const<Const, split_view>;      // exposition only
  using Base = maybe-const<Const, V>;                 // exposition only
  Parent* parent_ = nullptr;                          // exposition only
  iterator_t<Base> current_ = iterator_t<Base>();     // exposition only, present only if V models forward_­range
  
public:
// ...
};
```

When the base type `V` of `split_view` does not models `forward_range` such as `input_range`, the `outer-iterator` only contains a pointer, so it is obviously `copyable`. When `V` is a `forward_range`, the `current_` is also a `forward_iterator`, so it is `copyable`, which makes `outer-iterator` also `copyable`.

So why does the standard need to define a `begin()` function in `split_view::outer-iterator::value_type` based on a constraint that can never be satisfied?

I checked the earlier paper and did not find any discussion about this part, but this `begin()` function seems to be added after [LWG3276](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue3276).

Comment: a bit weird that the type is actually called `outer-iterator` with the `-`

Comment: This was added by P1862R1, trying to patch up the range adaptors when we made input iterators capable of being move-only. I think you are correct that as currently specified the constraint is useless. Want to file an LWG issue?

Comment: @T.C. It would be nice if there is one.

Comment: http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#submit_issue